# Android tts from service

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I wrote a little chat client that uses activity and service design for android.

The main time the client is running, only the service runs in background and notifys for new messages. Now my problem: The service should speak the incomming message with the help of the internal TTS system, but I have no how to build a "new TextToSpeech()" from the service!

Is there any possibility to create one without having an activity? And if, how?

regards christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer android developers TextToSpeech link [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html).

TextToSpeech constructors below.

```
TextToSpeech(Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener)
The constructor for the TextToSpeech class.
```

sample code refer [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html).